# r.js: Is it possible to specify multiple include/exclude on the command line?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

With r.js if I enter the following on the command line `exclude=bootstrap` the expected results are obtained.  However, if i enter `exclude=['bootstrap', 'jquery']` the following error occurs:

```
Tracing dependencies for: ['bootstrap'
Error: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory    'c:\users\justin\appdata\local\temp\tmpnojtra\core\js\['bootstrap'.js'
```

Clearly the array is not being parsed correctly by r.js, so i wonder if there is another syntax required to allow multiple includes/excludes or it's just not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses an unexpected syntax. See this [message](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/369#issuecomment-19286803) from RequireJS's author. Basically, you remove the brackets, spaces, string quotes that you'd put in the JavaScript, and what remains is what you put on the command line.

In your case `exclude=bootstrap,jquery` should do the trick.